# Set default value in a routing on each request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have got following routing, which basically enables me to keep the language within the url and makes sure only `de` and `fr` (constraint) is possible. In the `Default` - Routing, I set `de` as standard if there is no language in the url contained:

```
// Routing with language
routes.MapRoute("Default_with_language", "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
{
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
}, new { lang = "de|fr" });
// Standard-Routing
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
{
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
    lang = "de",
});
```

How can I change the default-language in each request? Let's say I have two Urls, one in german and one in french, I would like to have `lang = "fr"` if the french url is called...

Thx for any tipp
sl3dg3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Application_BeginRequest` handler, you can access the current route and you should be able to change the values using something like this.

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Add("lang", detectedLanguageFromUrl);
```

Hopefully, that's enough to make routing pick up the new value.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim: Thx for your answer. I figured out something similar at the same time:

```
var defaultRoute = RouteTable.Routes["Default"] as Route;
if (Request.Url.ToString().Contains("myFrenchUrl.ch"))
    defaultRoute.Defaults["lang"] = "fr";
else
    defaultRoute.Defaults["lang"] = "de";
```

sl3dg3